# Continuously Editing a Message

Tags: node.js, discord.js, embed

I was coding a bot and i wanted to make a live countdown from a certain time. I got the certain time right, but I had one problem. I couldnt edit the message so that it displays the remaining time. Here is my code currently:

```
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
let time = client.db.get(`time`)

const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setColor('#ff74fc')
    .setTitle('V2 Release Time')
    .setDescription('This command will be showing the countdown until the V2 cafe releases! ')
    .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/708130362122829876/746736868124524584/image0.jpg')
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Time', value: `${time} Seconds Left!` },
    )
    .setTimestamp()
    .setFooter('Flamgo Bot');

 return message.channel.send(exampleEmbed)

  const Edit = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .addFields(
        { name: 'Time', value: `${time} Seconds Left!` },
    )

 message.edit(Edit)


}
module.exports.help = {
 name: "v2time"
};
```

If anyone could help it would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you edit a message, you need to provide the full message that you will send. Currently, because `Edit` is an embed consisting of just 1 ‘Time’ field, the message will be updated with just that field and all the previous fields and other embed things will be removed.

Try this:

```js
const createEmbed = time => new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setColor('#ff74fc')
  .setTitle('V2 Release Time')
  .setDescription('This command will be showing the countdown until the V2 cafe releases! ')
  .setThumbnail('https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/708130362122829876/746736868124524584/image0.jpg')
  // addField can be used for adding a single field
  .addField('Time', `${time} Seconds Left!`)
  .setTimestamp()
  .setFooter('Flamgo Bot');

// Usage:
message.channel.send({embeds: [createdEmbed(client.db.get('time'))]});
message.edit({embeds: [createEmbed(client.db.get('time'))]});
// For Discord.js v12 use .send(embed)/.edit(embed)
```

For example, if you want to continuously update this embed, you could do something like this:

```js
/**
 * The timestamp of the date that you're counting down to
 * @type {number}
 */
const releaseDate = // ...

setInterval(() =>
  message.edit({embeds: [createEmbed(Math.round((releaseDate - Date.now()) / 1000))]})
    .catch(console.error),
  1000
)
```